# Strategy for debugging a python unittest assertion that only fails when not debugging

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, methodology

I'm working in PyCharm 3.0.2 using WinPython 2.7.5.3 when running my unit test in debug mode all of them are passing. However if I run them normally I have one that fails - specifically the result of the code below returns an extra unexpected item in the result list.

This is the failed test:

```
def test4(self):
        bz = BezNet()

        bz.insert([P(1, 1), P(2, 3)])
        bz.insert([P(1, 10), P(2, 30)])

        nodes = [n for n in bz.nodes]
        self.assertEqual(len(nodes), 4)
        edges = [e for e in bz.edges]
        self.assertEqual(len(edges), 2)

        bbzz = bz.separate()
        self.assertEqual(len(bbzz), 2) # assertioin fails (len==3) but ONLY in run mode
```

This is an excerpt of the part of the class `BezNet` being tested.

```
....
def _visit(self, a, nodes, edges):
    if a in nodes:
        return None
    for b in a._out:
        edges[a, b] = self._edges[a, b]
        self._visit(b, nodes, edges)
    nodes.add(a)

def separate(self):
    result = []
    while len(self._nodes):
        nodes = set()
        edges = {}
        for x in self._nodes:
            start = x
            break

        self._visit(start, nodes, edges)
        part = BezNet()
        part._nodes = nodes
        self._nodes.difference_update(nodes)
        part._edges = edges
        for e in edges:
            del self._edges[e]
        result.append(part)

    return result
....
```

The rest of the class is rather large so I won't include it here unless someone thinks it could be at fault in which case I will edit. [I'm not looking for a solution to the bug in my code yet, just how to go about tracking it when the tools are playing up]

My question is what could be happening under the hood to be causing this and what strategies one could use to go about tracing the problem?

Comment: Looks like you have yourself a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, they say naming the problem is half the solution (or something to that effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular circumstance the Heisenbug was due to the arbitrary ordering when the `set` type is iterated which happens to be repeatable but different between run and debug modes see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848091/python-set-iteration-order-varies-from-run-to-run)... My bad.

*In the end the solution came from copious print statements and waiting for that flash of inspiration of what documentation to double check.*