# Wrong code in implementation of Depth First Search

Tags: python-3.x, depth-first-search

I was looking at a code for Depth First Search in a website (https://brilliant.org/wiki/depth-first-search-dfs/). However the implementation seems wrong.This is the code they posted

```
def depth_first_search(graph):
    visited, stack = set(), [root]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
    return visited
```

This particular line throws an error

```
stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
```

This is my complete program

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'S'], 'B': ['A'], 'C': ['S', 'F', 'D', 'E'],
     'D': ['C'], 'E': ['H', 'C'], 'F': ['C', 'G'], 'G': ['S', 'F', 'H'], 'H': ['G', 'E'], 'S': ['A', 'G', 'C']}

def depth_first_search(graph, root):
    visited, stack = set(), [root]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
    return visited

print(depth_first_search(graph, 'A'))
```

This is the error the program encounters

```
File "/home/souvik/Sublime-text programs/TestCode124.py", line 47, in 
depth_first_search
    stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'set'
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining the values of `graph` to be lists, but the function is expecting them to be sets:

```
graph = {
         'A': {'B', 'S'}, 
         'B': {'A'}, 
         'C': {'S', 'F', 'D', 'E'},
         ...
        }
```

Comment: Ok now the code runs but it displays different answer everytime I run it.Why is that?

Comment: Sets are unordered, and [will be iterated in a different order between runs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32529871/789671). That would be the flaw in that function. It implements a DFS properly, but the return value is useless.