# How to create a dictionary where keys remain the same but new values are added?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary where the keys remain the same while I can add new values. I'll then be able to use this dictionary to create a dataframe in Pandas and generate an excel file as my output. However, when I try the following code I can't create the dictionary.

```
labels = {'name','currency','balance'}
name =['Mark','Jack','Tom','John']
currency = ['AUD','USD','GBP','GBP']
balance = [900,800,700,1000]

res = {element: zip(name,currency,balance) for element in labels} 
res
```

Any suggestion on why this is the case or alternative way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't create the dictionary"? You are creating a dictionary.. but you are not printing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

labels = {'name','currency','balance'}
name =['Mark','Jack','Tom','John']
currency = ['AUD','USD','GBP','GBP']
balance = [900,800,700,1000]

df = pd.DataFrame({lab:val for lab, val in zip(labels, [name, currency, balance])})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    name    currency    balance
0   Mark    AUD         900
1   Jack    USD         800
2   Tom     GBP         700
3   John    GBP         1000
```

Comment: Note that iteration order on sets is not guaranteed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848091/set-iteration-order-varies-from-run-to-run Labels should be a list if the order matters.