# How to put elements into few buckets (probably with itertools.combinations())?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I need to iterate through all possible combinations, putting elements from initial iterable into multiple buckets.
Illustration: Put `ABCDEFG` into two buckets with lengths `3` and `2` -->

```
[ABC, DE], [ABC, DF], [ABC, DG], [ABD, CE], [ABD, EF], ..., [CDE, FG]
```

No repeats, only unique combinations in each bucket (without permutations).

Edit: The buckets are important because `ABC, DE` and `ABD, CE` considered as different combinations (still the same 5 elements overall but distributed differently in buckets). While `ABC, DE` and `ACB, DE` considered as the same combination.
The order change within bucket is not a different combination. While moving element between buckets is a different combination.

I suppose I should use [itertools.combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) some way:

```
itertools.combinations('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC, ABD, ..., EFG
```

or combine it with something.

But I'm struggling to figure out how to further distribute the output across **multiple buckets** of different lengths.

Comment: The buckets are mostly irrelevant.  Just pick all combinations of length 5.  Use the first 3 and the next 2,

Comment: Are `[ABC, DE]` and `[ABE, DC]` considered different?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Yes, that's the whole point. I've edited my question with clarification.

Comment: @TimRoberts Wouldn't get all (wasn't clear when you commented).

Comment: @MicroElf I added a variant for working with an arbitrary number of bins to my answer (per your old comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's on possible implementation that relies on the elements of the "sample space" being [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3.12/glossary.html#term-hashable). This assumes that it matters which bucket an element falls in, so particular `[ABC, DE]` and `[ABD, CE]` are considered two different outcomes.

```
import itertools
from typing import Iterable, Iterator, TypeVar


_T = TypeVar("_T")


def two_bin_combs(
    iterable: Iterable[_T], b1: int, b2: int
) -> Iterator[tuple[tuple[_T, ...], tuple[_T, ...]]]:
    space = set(iterable)
    for left in itertools.combinations(space, b1):
        for right in itertools.combinations(space - set(left), b2):
            yield left, right
```

Then

```
sample_space = "ABCDEFG"
buckets = list(two_bin_combs(sample_space, 3, 2))

print(len(buckets))
print(buckets)
```

outputs

```
210
[
    (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('E', 'D')),
    (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('C', 'E')),
    (('A', 'B', 'E'), ('C', 'D')), 
    (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('E', 'B')), 
    (('A', 'C', 'E'), ('D', 'B'))
    # ...
    (('C', 'F', 'G'), ('D', 'E')), 
    (('D', 'E', 'F'), ('G', 'C')), 
    (('D', 'E', 'G'), ('F', 'C')), 
    (('D', 'F', 'G'), ('C', 'E')), 
    (('E', 'F', 'G'), ('D', 'C')),
]
```

Note that the output order is *not deterministic*, since it depends on [set iteration order, which can vary run-to-run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3848091/11082165).

---

This approach can also be generalized to an arbitrary number of bins:

```
def bin_combs(
    iterable: Iterable[_T], *bin_sizes: int
) -> Iterator[tuple[tuple[_T, ...], ...]]:

    total_space = frozenset(iterable)
    if len(total_space) < sum(bin_sizes):
        raise ValueError("total size of bins exceeds size of sample space")

    def _bin_combs(
        space: frozenset[_T], *bin_sizes: int
    ) -> Iterator[tuple[tuple[_T, ...], ...]]:

        if not bin_sizes:
            yield ()
            return

        curr_size, *remaining = bin_sizes

        for head in itertools.combinations(space, curr_size):
            for tail in _bin_combs(space - frozenset(head), *remaining):
                yield (head,) + tail

    return _bin_combs(total_space, *bin_sizes)
```

Comment: Is there a good reason you `yield from` instead of `return`?

Comment: @KellyBundy Nope, I like `return` better. Edited

Comment: Ok. *Sometimes* it's needed but almost always I've seen it, it just added an unnecessary generator iterator wrapper, slowing things down.

Comment: Oh, I mean, sometimes in "similar" cases, where a function creates some iterator and then only does `yield from` that iterator. It's such cases where `return` is usually better, that's what I meant. (And the exception is when the iterator would otherwise shut down, like `with open(filename) as f: return f` wouldn't work, and a `yield from` keeps it alive.)